# Bitbucket Pipelines - mvn clean install not working with JavaFX

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, maven-3, bitbucket-pipelines

I am using Bitbucket Pipelines for building a project from our university.

Here is my configuration from bitbucket-pipelines.yml:

```
image: maven:3.3.9-jdk-8

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - mvn -f EasyDiet_JavaFX_View/pom.xml clean install
```

And here is some of the compilation error -> relates to JavaFX:

```
ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/EasyDiet_JavaFX_View/src/at/fhv/easyDiet/teamC/presentation/patientFile/PatientFileController.java:[11,19] package javafx.fxml does not exist
[ERROR] /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/EasyDiet_JavaFX_View/src/at/fhv/easyDiet/teamC/presentation/patientFile/PatientFileController.java:[12,28] package javafx.scene.control does not exist
[ERROR] /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/EasyDiet_JavaFX_View/src/at/fhv/easyDiet/teamC/presentation/patientFile/PatientFileController.java:[13,27] package javafx.scene.layout does not exist
[ERROR] /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/EasyDiet_JavaFX_View/src/at/fhv/easyDiet/teamC/presentation/patientFile/PatientFileController.java:[14,27] package javafx.scene.layout does not exist
[ERROR] /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/EasyDiet_JavaFX_View/src/at/fhv/easyDiet/teamC/presentation/patientFile/PatientFileController.java:[15,20] package javafx.stage does not exist
[ERROR] /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/EasyDiet_JavaFX_View/src/at/fhv/easyDiet/teamC/presentation/patientFile/PatientFileController.java:[27,13] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class VBox
  location: class at.fhv.easyDiet.teamC.presentation.patientFile.PatientFileController
[ERROR] /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/EasyDiet_JavaFX_View/src/at/fhv/easyDiet/teamC/presentation/patientFile/PatientFileController.java:[29,13] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class BorderPane
  location: class at.fhv.easyDiet.teamC.presentation.patientFile.PatientFileController
[ERROR] /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/EasyDiet_JavaFX_View/src/at/fhv/easyDiet/teamC/presentation/patientFile/PatientFileController.java:[336,12] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Stage
  location: class at.fhv.easyDiet.teamC.presentation.patientFile.PatientFileController
```

And here some output of the build failure:

```
    INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12.828 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-10-19T10:18:57+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/282M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) on project easydiet-view: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/EasyDiet_JavaFX_View/src/at/fhv/easyDiet/teamC/presentation/patientFile/PatientFileController.java:[11,19] package javafx.fxml does not exist
[ERROR] /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/EasyDiet_JavaFX_View/src/at/fhv/easyDiet/teamC/presentation/patientFile/PatientFileController.java:[12,28] package javafx.scene.control does not exist
[ERROR] /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/EasyDiet_JavaFX_View/src/at/fhv/easyDiet/teamC/presentation/patientFile/PatientFileController.java:[13,27] package javafx.scene.layout does not exist
[ERROR] /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/EasyDiet_JavaFX_View/src/at/fhv/easyDiet/teamC/presentation/patientFile/PatientFileController.java:[14,27] package javafx.scene.layout does not exist
[ERROR] /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/EasyDiet_JavaFX_View/src/at/fhv/easyDiet/teamC/presentation/patientFile/PatientFileController.java:[15,20] package javafx.stage does not exist
[ERROR] /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/EasyDiet_JavaFX_View/src/at/fhv/easyDiet/teamC/presentation/patientFile/PatientFileController.java:[27,13] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class VBox
[ERROR] location: class at.fhv.easyDiet.teamC.presentation.patientFile.PatientFileController
[ERROR] /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/EasyDiet_JavaFX_View/src/at/fhv/easyDiet/teamC/presentation/patientFile/PatientFileController.java:[29,13] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class BorderPane
[ERROR] location: class at.fhv.easyDiet.teamC.presentation.patientFile.PatientFileController
```

If i build it locally on my Mac it works fine, but if i try with Bitbucket Pipelines i only get those errors. I have already tried with the default maven:3.3.3 image.

How is it possible to build JavaFX in Bitbucket Pipelines?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
image: maven:3-jdk-8

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - apt-get update
          - apt-get install -y openjfx
          - mvn clean install
```

Comment: Once javafx was installed, do the added lines still need to be there?